# MIGS Payment Gateway - Multiple Currencies/Merchants

Tags: payment-gateway, opencart

I am working on an e-commerce site that uses Open Cart and the MIGS Payment Gateway. I am using HSCB as the bank. My client wants two currencies supported on the shopping cart. Now that I have enabled two currencies in open cart, I cannot figure out how to configure two currencies in the MIGS Module which has as two different merchant accounts, as the MIGS Module in Open Cart allows me to enter only one Merchant Account.

Any help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

you need to purchase extension from
http://www.fido-x.net/index.php?route=product/product&product_id=66/

then you can insert multiple merchant id for multiple store

Answer (score 0):

You will need to duplicate the module files, and rename them all to migs2 or something along those lines. The files are all going to be called migs.php or migs.tpl I'm guessing, although it's not part of the standard opencart install. If you contact the developer, they may be able to help with getting it duplicated